# I have been getting duplicate value from my inner join table

Tags: php, mysql

[image]enter image description hereI have been using this sql code on my php. However, for every product i have been getting twice of them or a duplicate of them. How should i write to make it do not duplicate the product i get and just get once?

```
  <?php
 include ('classes/functions.php');

 if(isset($_POST['user_id'])){
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$check_receipt = "select  si.shipping_name,
    si.shipping_address,
    si.shipping_contact,
    si.shipping_email,
    o.order_date,
    o.trx_id,
    o.tracking_num,
    o.quantity,
    o.store_id,
    o.product_id,
    p.product_title,
    p.product_price,
    p.product_img1,
    p.product_weight
 from shipping_infos si
 inner join orders o
 on si.user_id = o.user_id 
 inner join products p 
on p.product_id = o.product_id
 where si.user_id='".$user_id."' order by o.trx_id;" ;

        $run_receipt_checking = mysqli_query($con, $check_receipt);
        $result = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_receipt_checking)){
    array_push($result,
    array(
          'shipping_name'=>$row[0],
          'shipping_address'=>$row[1],
          'shipping_contact'=>$row[2],
          'shipping_email'=>$row[3],
          'order_date'=>$row[4],
          'trx_id'=>$row[5],
          'tracking_num'=>$row[6],  
          'quantity'=>$row[7],
          'store_id'=>$row[8],
          'product_id'=>$row[9],
          'product_title'=>$row[10],              
          'product_price'=>$row[11],
          'product_img1'=>$row[12],     
          'product_weight'=>$row[13]          

));
}
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
}
```

?>

Comment: I think it's a problem with the PHP not the SQL. Could you post more code on how you run the query in PHP?

Comment: Add `distinct` immediately following `select`

Comment: It would be good to ask if there are duplicate entries within the database itself?

Comment: You should provide sample data and show what the duplicates are.

Comment: There are no duplicate entries as i have look at it.

Comment: PHP looks okay which leads me to believe that Gordons logic is correct. I find it's much easier to fix technical issues like this by testing the queries directly in the database first. So in say phpmyadmin, go to the SQL tab and try with a simple query and work it up in there until you get the correct data returned, then you can use that query in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicates in the result set imply multiple matches in the joins. Without sample data, it is really hard to tell where it is occurring.

If I had to guess based on the query, then would guess that users could have multiple rows in `shipping_infos`. There are definitely other possibilities, but I would start with a simple query and build up to the final query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your `p.product_id` is an unique field in your DB.

If so you could add `GROUP BY p.product_id` at the end of your statement.

```
$check_receipt = "select  si.shipping_name,
    si.shipping_address,
    si.shipping_contact,
    si.shipping_email,
    o.order_date,
    o.trx_id,
    o.tracking_num,
    o.quantity,
    o.store_id,
    o.product_id,
    p.product_title,
    p.product_price,
    p.product_img1,
    p.product_weight
  from shipping_infos si
  inner join orders o
on si.user_id = o.user_id 
 inner join products p 
on p.product_id = o.product_id
where si.user_id='".$user_id."' order by o.trx_id group by p.product_id;" ;
```